# Could not switch the monitor configuration (CTR 63)

Tags: 16.04

I've found quite some answers to that question, but none of the answers solved my problem.

When I lock my PC and come back after a while, usually one of my three screens (2x TFT + Laptop) is black and I get the error message:

> Could not switch the monitor configuration
>   Could not set the configuration for CTR 63

If I press close all three screens are working, but it moved all my windows around.

I am using a DELL Latitude E6440 with an integrated Intel graphics card.

`lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

The answers I've found:

1. Install graphic card driver, but those are usually for NVidia or ATI cards
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg` did nothing for me

Any other ideas?

Comment: I also have 16.04, and got this on a laptop (no external monitors). Only difference is that it says CRTC 442.